# How can a Tkinter work with a Listener together?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, pynput

I have written a Tkinter and I hope to have a Listener to monitor the Keyboard Input by Users. But when I use `mainloop()` to start the Tkinter, the Listener cannot work together with it, and will start until I quit Tkinter.

I have tried to add this Listener in Tkinter sub-unit, but it does not work as the same.

```
def initialization():
    print("Starting...")
    print("Start listener...")
    with mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick) as listener:
        listener.join()

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('800x80')
    root.resizable(height=True, width=True)
    root.overrideredirect(False)
    root.title('vENC Console')

    OneBtn = Button(root, command=initialization, text="One Button", width='30')
    root.mainloop()
```

How can I let them work together? Do I need to use multi-thread?

Comment: Are you trying to monitor mouse clicks when user is focused or not focused on tkinter?

Comment: @HenryYik In fact, I want to monitor the keyboard input, for example, when user send key F5, then, I will do some action in Tkinter.

Comment: There is a non- blocking solution on their website. `listener = mouse.Listener(...)` and then `listener.start()`.

Comment: I tried to use Thread.start and Join, but it does not work the same.

Comment: _A mouse listener is a threading.Thread_, so if you call `listen.join()` it will wait for the thread to terminate and so blocks the main thread of tkinter. I am not sure what does not work the same - can you clarify?

Comment: @HenryYik But it seems can work only once, I can monitor the mouse event, but only once, this thread cannot be alive forever.

Comment: if you are using the sample on their tutorial - it is intentional that the thread terminates itself after a `onpress` event.

Comment: I doubt that `pynput` will work with `tkinter` even if you use threading, because they both want to process user keyboard and mouse events — so it's an inherent conflict. You need to use one or the other.

Comment: @martineau   Below answer give the solution, we can use join() to realize the multi-threading, and I have tried the codes, it can work normally.

Answer (score 1):

Like practically all GUI toolkits, Tkinter is *event driven*. That means that *Tkinter* should handle mouse and keyboard events.
Widgets can register that they're interested in event by adding bindings for certain events. Tkinter *depends* on the flow of events to work.

Essentially, the `mainloop` waits for events to occur (keyboard, mouse, time-outs) and then calls any registered callbacks.

Adding another event handler separate from Tkinter will clash. On top of that, Tkinter is *not* thread-safe. If you must use threads you should make sure that only the main thread uses Tkinter functions and methods.

Basically, Tkinter and a Listener cannot work together.

So I would propose to you to use `bind_all` instead.
By using the `bind_all` method (read about it [here](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)) you can register a binding on the application level instead of for specific widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it this way

```
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick)
listener.start() # start thread

root.mainloop()

listener.stop()  # stop thread
listener.join()  # wait till thread really ends its job
```

And don't use `return False` in `onMouseClick` because it ends listener.

`tkinter` has own methods to get keys and mouse events so maybe you should use them. `Listener` can be useful if you have to catch event when tkinter's window is minimized and it doesn't get events from system.

---

**EDIT:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import mouse

def onMouseClick(*args):
    print(args)

root = tk.Tk()

listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick)
listener.start() # start thread

root.mainloop()

listener.stop()  # stop thread
listener.join()  # wait till thread really ends its job
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import mouse

def onMouseClick(*args):
    print(args)

def initialization():
    global listener

    print("Starting...")
    print("Start listener...")
    listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick)
    listener.start() # start thread

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    listener = None   

    root = tk.Tk()

    btn = tk.Button(root, command=initialization, text="One Button")
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    # stop listener if it was created
    if listener: # if listener is not None:
        print("Stop listener...")
        listener.stop()  # stop thread
        listener.join()  # wait till thread really ends its job
```

---

**EDIT:** example with button which stop listener

```
import tkinter as tk
from pynput import mouse

def onMouseClick(*args):
    print(args)

def on_start():
    global listener

    if not listener:
        print("Start listener...")
        listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=onMouseClick)
        listener.start() # start thread
    else:
        print("listener already running")

def on_stop():
    global listener

    if listener:
        print("Stop listener...")
        listener.stop()  # stop thread
        listener.join()  # wait till thread really ends its job
        listener = None  # to inform that listener doesn't exist
    else:
        print("listener not running")

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    print("Starting...")

    listener = None  # to keep listener

    root = tk.Tk()

    btn = tk.Button(root, command=on_start, text="Star Mouse Listener")
    btn.pack()

    btn = tk.Button(root, command=on_stop, text="Stop Mouse Listener")
    btn.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    # stop listener if it was created
    if listener: # if listener is not None:
        print("Stop listener...")
        listener.stop()  # stop thread
        listener.join()  # wait till thread really ends its job
```

Comment: It works! But why ```mainloop()``` must be between ```listener.start()``` and ```listener.join()```? Can I use ```mainloop``` firstly and then start Listener, then Join()?

Comment: `mailoop()` works all time till you close window - so listener after `mainloop()` will be created after you close window.

Comment: So, when I start listener by using '''listener.start()'''' and then '''mainloop()''', mainloop will not kill listener? Only block Listener? Then join() will let them work together?

Comment: listener creates separated thread to run it - so `mainloop()` doesn't block it and not kill it. They work at the same time but in different threads. And `join()` is used only to wait for listener's close (thread's close). You could even skip `join()` but then you may get error that thread wasn't close correctly (or something similar).

Comment: Yes, I remove join() and tried again. When I kill '''mainloop()'''', the listener will be killed the same time. Thanks a lot! It helps me to understand threading more deeply!

Comment: I released that I forgot `listener.stop()` in code. I added `listener.stop()` in answer. `stop()` stops thread and then we use `join()` to wait till thread ends it job - it may need time to clear some settings, remove elements, close files, etc. If you don't use it then system may remove thread from memory when program ends its job and thread may not have time to clean up - and it may give error.